# Unable to Set Width for Fragment Dynamically in the Program

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have created set of fragments inside the activity and set a default width to it.
I want to reset the fragment to width to FILL_PARENT on orientation change which is not happening.

How to set fragment width dynamically in Android 3.0 Honeycomb version?